# FIR filter design: how to input sine wave form

Tags: c++, filter, io

I am currently taking a class in school and I have to code FIR/IIR filter in C/C++.

As an input to the filter, 2kHz sine wave with white noise is used. Then, by inputting the sine wave to the C/C++ code, I need to observe the clean sine wave output. It's all done in software level.

My problem is that I don't know how to deal with this input/output of sine wave. For example, I don't know what type of file format I can use or need to use, I don't know how to make the sine wave form and etc.

This might be a very trivial question, but I have no clue where to begin.

Does anyone have any experience in this type of question or have any tips?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: are you asked to generated the input signal, or are you given it as a file ?

Comment: A file is not given. I need to come up with one.

Comment: if you have to generate it, use <math> hearder where you have the sin function, and the random function in <cstdlib>. That should be sufficient to generate a roughly noised sine wave. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

Comment: With the method you provided above, I will end up with a series of numbers which a sine wave can have, correct? However, I am not too sure, if this suits my purpose. Filter code is likely to have sampling portion of the input file as well. In this case, I think I would need a different type of input.

Comment: Ask one question at a time if you want to understand/be understood. I told you how to generate the input signal. I haven't dealt with the filter stage.

Comment: Once you succeed generating a sinewave at 2KHz, you have to compute the coefficients of your FIR filter. What about that ? You already have chosen them ?

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My apologies. I am so clueless, so I don't even know what's right question to ask, at this moment.

Comment: Yes, we are allowed to use Matlab FDA, with a given parameters, to obtain filter coefficients and I have them.

Comment: And once you have computed the FIR coefficient of your filter, you apply the formula that gives you the output nth sample y[n] = c0 xn + c1 xn-1 + .... If you compute y[n] for all the samples of your input signal, then you have the entire output y

Comment: I just said something wrong, the output is longer, it has more samples than the input.

Comment: I just saw a sample code, which uses the '*.pcm' wave form file as an input to the filter. Is that wave form ideally same as what I would get using <math> library? It's from:  http://sestevenson.wordpress.com/implementation-of-fir-filtering-in-c-part-1/

Comment: You told me you had no file as input. So I tell you to generate an array containing a sinewave, upon which you add a little random so as the sine wave will differ from a pure sinewave, and the random differences is the white noise. If you have a pcm file that contains a sinewave with noise you could use it, but you told me you had no input files.

Comment: I do not have that pcm file. It's someone else's file which is used for his/her filter code. (See the link from the above comment.) So, having said that, is the sine wave pcm file, in the link, ideally same as an array that I can make from <math> library?

Comment: Thanks for your patience by the way.

Comment: That's what I tell you. If you generate a sinewave array, and for each sample in the array you add a little random - which is the white noise - then you basically have a sound sample which is a sine wave slightly white noised. Et voilà.

Comment: Ah, okay, now, I understand :) I don't have any basics, so I didn't even realize they were ideally the same thing. Thank you Stephane!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating the sine wave at 2kHz means that you want to generate values over time that, when graphed, follow a sine wave.  Pick an amplitude (you didn't mention one), and pick your sample rate.  See the graph here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave); you want values that when plotted follow the sine wave graphed in 2D with the X axis being time, and the Y axis being the amplitude of the value you are measuring.

- amplitude (volts, degrees, pascals, milliamps, etc)
- frequency (2kHz, that is 2000 sine waves/second)
- sample rate (how many samples do you want per second)

Suppose you generate a file that has a time value and an amplitude measurement, which you would want to scale to your amplitude (more on this later).  So a device might give an 8-bit or 16-bit digital reading which represents either an absolute, or logarithmic measurement against some scale.

```
struct sample
{
    long usec; //microseconds (1/1,000,000 second)
    short value; //many devices give a value between 0 and 255
}
```

Suppose you generate exactly 2000 samples/second.  If you were actually measuring an external value, you would get the same value every time (see that?), which when graphed would look like a straight line.

So you want a sample rate higher than the frequency.  Suppose you sample as 2x the frequency.  Then you would see points 180deg off on the sine wave, which might be peaks, up or down slope, or where sine wave crosses zero.  A sample rate 4x the frequency would show a sawtooth pattern.  And as you increase the number of samples, your graph looks closer to the actual sine wave.  This is similar to the pixelization you see in 8-bit game sprites.

How many samples for any given sine wave would you think would give you a good approximation of a sine wave?  8? 16? 100? 500?  Suppose you sampled 1,000,000 times per second, then you would have 1,000,000/2,000 = 500 samples per sine wave.

- pick your sample rate (500)
- define your frequency (2000)
- decide how long to record your samples (5 seconds?)
- define your amplitude (device measures 0-255, but what is measured max?)

Here is code to generate some samples,

```
#define MAXJITTER (10)
#define MAXNOISE  (20)
int
generate_samples( long duration, //duration in microseconds
         int amplitude,   //scaled peak measurement from device
         int frequency,   //Hz > 0
         int samplerate ) //how many samples/second > 0
{
    long ts; //timestamp in microseconds, usec
    long sdelay; //sample delay in usec
    if(frequency<1) frequency1=1; //avoid division by zero
    if(samplerate<1) samplerate=1; //avoid division by zero
    sdelay = 1000000/samplerate; //usec delay between each sample
    sample m;
    int jitter, noise; //introduce noise here

    for(  long ts=0; ts<duration;  ts+=sdelay ) // //in usec (microseconds)
    {
        //jitter, sample not exactly sdelay
        jitter = drand48()*MAXJITTER - (MAXJITTER/2); // +/-1/2 MAXJITTER
        //noise is mismeasurement
        noise = drand48()*MAXNOISE - (MAXNOISE/2);    // +/-1/2 MAXNOISE

        m.usec = ts + jitter;
        //2PI in a full sine wave
        float period = 2*PI * (ts*1.0/frequency);
        m.value = sin( period );
        //write m to file or save me to array/vector
    }
    return 0; //return number of samples, or sample array, etc
}
```

First generate some samples,

```
generate_samples( 5*1000000, 100, 2000, 2000*50 );
```

You could graph the samples generated as a view of the noisy signal.

The above certainly answers many of your questions about how to record measurements, and what format is typically used.  And it shows how transit through the period of multiple sine waves, generate random samples with jitter and noise, and record samples over some time duration.

Building your filter is a second issue.  Writing the code to emulate the filter(s) described below is left as an exercise, or a second question as you glean more understanding,

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response

The generated sample of the signal (above) would be fed into the code you write to build the filter.  Expect that the output of the filter would be a new set of samples, perhaps with jitter, but expect that your filter would eliminate at least some of the noise.  You would then be able to graph the samples produced by the filter.

You might consider that converting the samples into a comma delimited file would enable you to load them into excel and graph them.  And it might help if you elucidated your electronics background, your trig knowledge, and how much you know about filters, etc.

Good luck!